# Entity Framework 6.1 RTM Licensing

Tags: entity-framework

We upgraded our project to EF 6.1 because there was a serious query bug in 6.0 and now we are nearing our production release date and EF 6.1 is still RTM.  I was gambling that EF 6.1 would hit full release before we did, and I lost.

Am I allowed to release my application using EF 6.1 RTM?  Are there any licensing considerations I need to be aware of since it is RTM and not fully released?

Comment: RTM *is* final release. EF doesn't do GA releases. It is released under the [Apache License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License).

Answer (score 0):

This is the official information about EF licensing at codeplex:

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/license